# Why am I getting a CS1666 error, apparently at runtime?

Tags: c#, pointers, unsafe

I have these 2 structs:

```
[StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)]
unsafe struct ReinterpretableStruct
{
    public int a; // 0 - 1 - 2 - 3
    public fixed byte buffer[4]; // 4 - 5 - 6 - 7
    public double x; // 8 - 9 - 10 - 11 - 12 - 13 - 14 - 15
}

[StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)]
unsafe struct OtherReinterpretableStruct
{
    public ushort a; // 0 - 1
    public fixed byte buffer[2]; // 2 - 3
    public float y; // 4 - 5 - 6 - 7
    public long w; // 8 - 9 - 10 - 11 - 12 - 13 - 14 - 15
}
```

They are both 16 bytes with no padding, as shown in the comments.
I have been messing around with the fixed buffers as well as pointer conversions, and am having a weird issue.

```
Assert.True(b.a == *(ushort*)&a.a);
string bufferAsUnsignedShort = (*(ushort*) b.buffer).ToString();
Assert.True(*(ushort*)b.buffer == *((ushort*)&a) + 1);
Assert.True(b.y == *(float*)a.buffer);
Assert.True(b.w == *(long*)&a.x);
```

The first line works as expected, passing the Assert.
However, the third line fails the assertion. The weird part is that when I place a breakpoint on the 3rd line, this is what I see:
[image: A picture of a VS breakpoint showing the text "CS1666: You cannot use fixed size buffers contained in unfixed expressions. Try using the fixed statement."]
[Description: A picture of a VS breakpoint showing the text "CS1666: You cannot use fixed size buffers contained in unfixed expressions. Try using the fixed statement."]

This itself is weird to me, as that's a compiler error and no issues were had compiling. Without the breakpoint, it runs, just not as expected.

I tried, naturally, to fix a) the struct and b) the buffer itself but neither worked, saying something along the lines of "Cannot take address of already fixed variable through `fixed`

How do I resolve this?

Comment: I assume the error message is from the debugger trying to make sense of "b.buffer"

Answer (score 0):

I am not seeing any issue here. Try the following and see what you get:

```
using System;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;

namespace Demo
{
    [StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)]
    unsafe struct ReinterpretableStruct
    {
        public       int    a;         // 0 - 1 - 2 - 3
        public fixed byte   buffer[4]; // 4 - 5 - 6 - 7
        public       double x;         // 8 - 9 - 10 - 11 - 12 - 13 - 14 - 15
    }

    [StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)]
    unsafe struct OtherReinterpretableStruct
    {
        public       ushort a;         // 0 - 1
        public fixed byte   buffer[2]; // 2 - 3
        public       float  y;         // 4 - 5 - 6 - 7
        public       long   w;         // 8 - 9 - 10 - 11 - 12 - 13 - 14 - 15
    }

    class Program
    {
        public static void Main()
        {
            unsafe
            {
                var a = new ReinterpretableStruct();
                var b = new OtherReinterpretableStruct();

                int size1 = *(ushort*) b.buffer;
                int size2 = *((ushort*) &a) + 1;

                Console.WriteLine(size1);
                Console.WriteLine(size2);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

When I run that, I see the following output:

```
0
1
```

This is the expected output given the default-initialised structs.

Comment: The only difference between yours and mine is that my method isn't static - but surely that wouldn't affect it

Comment: @John I built it with .Net 4.7.2, AnyCPU and with the latest version of C# and Visual Studio, in case that's of relevance.

Comment: exact same, except C# 7.3 not 8.0, though you may have meant that